# Linking to Edit Action in Rails Dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, edit, form-for

I have a drop-down that shows all the different industry objects in my application, I want to have a user select a industry from the drop-down then link to the edit page.  Currently the submit button is linking straight to the update action.

```
<%= form_for [@industry] do |f| %>
  <%= f.select( :id, options_for_select(Industry.get_names), :method => "Edit") %>
  <%= f.submit "Edit Industry", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: try move ":method => 'Edit'" to form_for

Comment: @gFontaniva this will submit to the 'show' action for the pre-defined `@industry` object, not the thing the user selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a form: a straight html form will submit a request (POST by default) to a fixed url, and optionally add some parameters.

To make the form send you to a page which shows the info for the object the user selected in the dropdown, you will need to make sure you have an route and action which looks **just** at the params, and not the url itself, in order to decide what to do.

In the standard rails setup, `params[:id]` is baked into the url itself, eg `/industries/123/edit`.  Your form will have a url with the id of the @industry object you have defined previously, which isn't what you want.  You will need to make sure you have an action which just looks in params to decide which `Industry` object to actually load up.

For example, you could set up a route like so:

```
get '/industry/edit', to: 'industry#edit'
```

Now, you can get to the edit action for an industry object, passing `params[:id]` ( which the code in the action looks for) by using the traditional `/industry/123/edit` **OR** our new route, `/industry/edit?id=123`.

We can now use the second route in the form:

```
<%= form_tag "/industry/edit", :method => :get do %>
  <%= select_tag( :id, options_for_select(Industry.get_names)) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Edit Industry", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT:  i changed this from being a form_for (which revolves around editing an AR object) to a form_tag, which means changing the f.select and f.submit to a select_tag and submit_tag.

Comment: I get private method `select' called for nil:NilClass, Industry.get_names returns all the names of the Industries as an array.  Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Whoops - sorry.  I forgot that when you do a form_tag you lose the f object.  I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Oh, and also - you should amend `Industry.get_names` to return an array where each entry is a sub-array with `[industry.name, industry.value]`.  This will mean that the *name* of the industry is displayed in the dropdown, but the *id* of the industry is passed through into the params.